# Multiple Java GUI Components in one cell of GridLayout?

Tags: java, user-interface, cells, grid-layout

Is it possible to add three JTextFields inside of one cell in a Java GridLayout?  If not, how can I have a grid based layout where I can set the preferred height of each cell and add more than one Java GUI component to a cell?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should add them all to one panel and add this panel to the `GridLayout` panel.

For example:

```
JPanel inPanel = new JPanel();           // Create new panel
inPanel.add(new JTextField("TF1");       // Add components to it
inPanel.add(new JTextField("TF2");
inPanel.add(new JTextField("TF3");
myGridPanel.add(inPanel);                // Add the panel to a your "GridLayout" panel
```

Also, maybe [GridBagLayout](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/gridbag.html) will fit your needs.

Comment: @user665926: You don't add components to a layout, you add components to containers (such as a JPanel) that uses a layout. Please read the layout tutorials in the Oracle Swing tutorials as it will explain all.